# Prob. 2, Sec. 3.9 in Erwine Kreyszig's INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS: Inversion and adjointness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $T \colon H \to H$ be a bijective bounded linear operator whose inverse is bounded. Then how to show that $(T^*)^{-1}$ exists and 
$$(T^*)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^*?$$

My effort:

Let $x, y \in H$ such that $y = Tx$ and $T^* y = 0$. Then we have 
$$0 = \langle T^* y , x \rangle = \langle y, Tx \rangle = \langle y, y \rangle,$$
which implies that $y = 0$. Thus $T^*$ is injective.

Can we now say that $(T^*)^{-1}$ exists?

Is it possible now to show that $T^* \colon H \to H$ is surjective?

Finally, how to derive the relation 
$$(T^*)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^*?$$

Comment: $ST=TS=I$ gives $T^{\star}S^{\star}=S^{\star}T^{\star}=I^{\star}=I$.